# Evaluate OnPlatform<T>

Tags: xamarin.forms

If I retrieve an instance of `OnPlatform<T>` from a resource dictionary using code, how do I evaluate it for the current platform?

```
public static string FontName =>
   ((OnPlatform<string>) Application.Current.Resources["Font"]) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it the next way:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="MyPadding"
         x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
            iOS="0, 20, 0, 0"
            Android="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

var thickness = (OnPlatform<Thickness>)Application.Current.Resources["MyPadding"];
var realThickness = (Thickness)thickness;
```

or

```
var thickness = (Thickness)(OnPlatform<Thickness>)Application.Current.Resources["MyPadding"];
```

Alternatively you can create an extension method:

```
public static class ApplicationExtensions
{
    public static T GetResourceOnPlatform<T>(this Application app, string key) => (T)(OnPlatform<T>)app.Resources[key];
}
```

and then consume it the next way:

```
var thickness = Application.Current.GetResourceOnPlatform<Thickness>("MyPadding");
```